# numericupdown reset to 100 automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a numericupdown in my form and set its maximum value to 2000 although whenever i type a number bigger than 100 in and leave it the value reset to 100 automatically? I try this code to correct that but the behaviour doesn't correct.

```
private void answer_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Select the whole answer in the NumericUpDown control.
    NumericUpDown answerBox = sender as NumericUpDown;

    if (answerBox != null)
    {
        int lengthOfAnswer = answerBox.Value.ToString().Length;
        answerBox.Select(0, lengthOfAnswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried which you have described here, but i didn't got your problem

Comment: have you added any event LostFocus or Leave to the control ?

Comment: Your question is unclear!. You say `my numericupdown resets its value to 100 when I leave the control`. Why then your code seems to be for the Enter event? And what has that code to do with the problem stated?

Comment: i use code in msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492138.aspx

Comment: question: when you first click on the control, does the "0" get highlighted, or does it stay as it is, with the blinking cursor to the left of the zero?

Comment: Clearly your assumption that the Maximum property is set to 2000 is not correct.  The code snippet doesn't do anything useful about it.

Answer (score 1):

This code selects all text in the spin box of `NumericUpDown` control. Why? Because when you use `Tab` to navigate through controls to `NumericUpDown`, text will not be selected and input will start in first position. So, if you already have value `5` and type `6`, then you will get `65`. If all text will be selected, then selected value `5` will be replaces with new value `6`.

Resetting value to max value is a default `NumericUpDown` control behavior. If entered number exceeds allowed maximum, then when you leave `NumericUpDown` control it's value will be replaces with allowed maximum.

*Keep in mind*, that actual value of `NumericUpDown` changed only when you leave control or use arrow keys to change value. When you type in text, value will not change until focus leaves spin box.

**Verify to which control you have set Maximum value**
`NumericUpDown` changes his value automatically only if entered value exceeds `Maximum` or `Minimum` value of *that particular instance*. So, it's obvious that your control has `Maximum` set to `100`. Possibly you changed maximum value of some other control.

Comment: It doesn't make sense though that he's set the max value to 2000, yet it resets to 100

Comment: I think he changes value by typing it, not by setting `Max` property. Or maybe he changed max value of some other control. Otherwise it is not possible. Also it's important to notice what OP code really does.

Comment: yeah, he's typing in values, but he says whenever he makes it more than 100, it jumps back to 100 "automatically". If it's automatic, I'd assume it's either Max or Min doing its job. But he says he's set the Max to 2000, so it oughtn't jump to 100

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a full analysis of this but I had similar problem when using this code:

```
<wf:NumericUpDown x:Name="NumericKernalSize"  Width="50" Height="22" Visible="True" ValueChanged="NumericKernalSize_ValueChanged" BorderStyle="FixedSingle" Value="201" Minimum="0" Maximum="1000" />
```

What was happening was that the value = 201 seemed to be exceeding the default maximum of 100 before the maximum value was set to the desired max of 1000.

If you set the maximum before the value, the problem doesn't arise e.g. the following worked for me:-

```
<wf:NumericUpDown x:Name="NumericKernalSize"  Width="50" Height="22" Visible="True" ValueChanged="NumericKernalSize_ValueChanged" BorderStyle="FixedSingle" Minimum="0" Maximum="1000" Value="201"/>
```

Hope this is of help to someone as it is tricky to catch this problem...

Cheers...

Comment: Its Winforms, not WPF.